# How do you find the phone number on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, phone-number

Is there a way to find the phone number of the current phone on the Windows Phone 7 OS? The DeviceExtendedProperties does not provide such information (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the phone number in the current release.

You might want to play with the [Phone Number Chooser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonenumberchoosertask(v=vs.92).aspx) to let the user select their own number rather than typing it

Comment: @Dylan it makes sense from the point of view of security and the protection of users data from being obtained by an application without the users express permission.